# Google Spreadsheets ImportXML into 2 columns

Tags: xml, xpath, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an xml document that looks like this:

```
<Time>
<ID>22653948</ID>
<Job>
<ID>J000010</ID>
<Name>NEP0001_Evesham</Name>
</Job>
<Task>
<ID>12379652</ID>
<Name>Assemble</Name>
</Task>
<Staff>
<ID>68684</ID>
<Name>Ruiardh Robinson</Name>
</Staff>
<Date>2012-10-29T00:00:00</Date>
<Minutes>180</Minutes>
<Note/>
<Billable>true</Billable>
</Time>
```

The document contains multiple `<Time>` entries and what I'm trying to do is import all the `<Date>` and `<Minutes>` fields for each task, only where the date contains the string "2014". I can import all the dates fields from 2014 using:

```
=QUERY(ImportXML('Time Data'!F2, "//Time/Date"), "SELECT * WHERE Col1 contains '2014-04'")
```

But I can't get the corresponding minutes field for the same entry, I know you can do multiple xpath queries using the `|` operator and I tried the following but it doesn't work as it just returns the first date field from the first entry for some reason.

```
=QUERY(ImportXML('Time Data'!F2, "//Time/Date | //Time/Minutes"), "SELECT * WHERE Col1 contains '2014-04'")
```

Does anyone know how I can import both columns only where the date contains "2014"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

```
//Time/*[self::Date or self::Minutes]
```

however the way google reads the XML, this will populate across rows and not columns, so if you have the query in A1 the result will be

```
   A                    B                  C     ...
1 2012-10-29T00:00:00
2 180
```

So if you want this to be in columns you could just add a 2nd ImportXML query in B1 that uses `//Time/Minutes`

Personaly however I'd just import the whole XML in another sheet and then query that.

Btw you could also use `//Time[starts-with(Date, '2014')]` instead of wrapping the ImportXML in QUERY

Comment: Thanks, I got it working using the `starts-with` bit, however now it imports every row in each `<Time>` tag, e.g. ID, Job, Staff etc. It doesn't matter that much, but I was wondering if there is a way to only import the dates and minutes entries

Comment: The only way I think is to have 2 import statements  next to each other https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/195LkhZPjZcqPiG22z1h06E8pjoCi1VAZ8oaV1GwxlQo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Cheers mate, thanks for the example. Was exactly what I was trying to do.